# JQuery get parent input in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where the tbody is created inside a loop (so, I can't have id because it will have the same id). The last  is a input type button. How can I get the values of previous inputs?

```
<table class="table-b tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
   <thead>
        <!--- <th> here --->
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <!--- LOOP Start --->
     <tr>
       <TD align=center><Input Type=Text Name=Amount Value="10"></TD>
        <TD align=center><Input Type=Text Name=Name Value="Name Test"></TD>
       <TD align=center><INPUT TYPE="button" onclick="test()" VALUE="Update"></TD>
     </tr>
     <!--- LOOP End --->
 </table>

 <script>
    function test(){
        // Using JQuery, how can I get the Amount and Name values?
    }
 </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be great to make something like `onclick="test(this)"` then `this` will be resolve to the button element, then inside the `function test(element){ you can select tds siblings  for the element  }`, this could be hint for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you access to the `input` and `name` near what you clicked. It works by assigning an event listener on all the buttons so that when it's clicked it will traverse the DOM tree to get the appropriate values.

```
$('.table-b input[type="button"]').click(function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var amount = tr.find('input[name="Amount"]').val();
  var name = tr.find('input[name="Name"]').val();
});
```

Comment: `$('input[type="text;"]')` why the `;`?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about

Comment: But I'll have a lot of <td> with the name "amount" and "name". It will be inside a loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends how you want the data. If you want each PAIR of amount and name, and you're going to do something with each set of values, what I wrote above is correct. If you want them all in the same big list then that would be a different strategy.

Comment: If you want to get all the rows in that table use this solution, and in each `tr` select your td by index or class name

Comment: You don't need to select the `td` at all, just write it how I have above and it will get the exact input values you need.

Comment: I see. I think I explained wrong. I just want the pair of inputs above the button that I clicked.

Comment: I think something like my comment, when you click on button you get the amount and name in the same row, I explained in comment early

Comment: I edited my answer @MaxBoy now it will do what you want

Comment: Edited answer very elegant, much more than mine. This will do it

Comment: Yes Agree, Thumb up +1

Answer (score 2):

## You have some issues in your approach

Some of your element's tags, attributes have capitalized letters.

```
<TD align=center><Input Type=Text Name=Amount Value="10"></TD>
 ^                ^     ^    ^    ^           ^
```

Missing `</tbody>`.

```
     </tr>
     <- Here is missing </tbody>
 </table>
```

Use event delegation to your `buttons` as follow

```
$(document).on('click', '.table-b tbody tr td [type="button"]', function() {...}
```

## Suggested approach

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var obj = {
  "amount": $tr.find('[name="Amount"]').val(),
  "name": $tr.find('[name="Name"]').val()
}

console.log(obj);
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.table-b tbody tr td [type="button"]', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var obj = {
    "amount": $tr.find('[name="Amount"]').val(),
    "name": $tr.find('[name="Name"]').val()
  }
  
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-b tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
  <thead>
    <!--- <th> here --->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--- LOOP Start --->
    <tr>
      <td align=center>
        <input type=text name="Amount" value="10">
      </td>
      <td align=center>
        <input type=text name=Name value="Name Test1">
      </td>
      <td align=center>
        <input type="button" value="Update">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=center>
        <input type=text name="Amount" value="11">
      </td>
      <td align=center>
        <input type=text name=Name value="Name Test2">
      </td>
      <td align=center>
        <input type="button" value="Update">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!--- LOOP End --->
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table class="table-b tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
 <thead>
    <!--- <th> here --->
</thead>
<tbody>
 <!--- LOOP Start --->
 <tr>
   <TD align=center><Input Type=Text Name=Amount Value="10"></TD>
    <TD align=center><Input Type=Text Name=Name Value="Name Test"></TD>
   <TD align=center><INPUT TYPE="button" onclick="test(this)" VALUE="Update"></TD>
 </tr>
 <!--- LOOP End --->
</table>

<script>
function test(obj){
  amount = $(obj).prev().prev().val();
  name = $(obj).prev().val;
}
```

Comment: But I'll have a lot of <td> with the name "amount" and "name". It will be inside a loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: onclick="test(this)" have you added that in your code